# What are alternatives to the verb "follow"?

Tags: ios, terminology, activity-feed

I'm designing a mobile app that has an independent activity feed. One option on items in the feed is to "follow" individual stories/threads. What verbiage can I use to convey the idea of "following" a story, without using the word "follow"? (Or, should I stick with "follow" because of it's wide acceptance?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add to the other answers - Track and Watch are good options, but are better used in the context of verb + noun.

For example: 
*Track this ____*, is good - like *Track this event* as used on Lanyrd and other conference websites, and *Track this story* as used by lots of news publications.

[image]

*Watch this ____* is good too, like *Watch this thread* as used on many forum/discussion websites.

I think you'd have to work hard with location, whitespace and layout to make it really clear what the standalone use of the word *Track* or *Watch* actually refers to - especially the word *Watch*. Watch what? Watch a video?

Even if you stick with *Follow*, the same applies - Twitter for example use a 'Follow' button only where it's absolutely clear who is being followed. In some places they use 'Follow me' instead. In a location where you may have a topic, a story, a user, an author, a thread, a tag, or other content, it might not be 100% obvious to all users what a standalone *Follow* button might relate to.

Comment: Or you can use the verb alone in context (adjacent/touching the post). Like some of the social platforms do for following individuals, posts or pages.

Answer (score 3):

**Subscribe** can work. So can **Track**.

Answer (score 3):

**Watch** or **Watching** works too..Used a lot in forums for watching topics.

Answer (score 0):

You could also describe the end result instead. What does it mean to "follow" a thread?

**E-mail me** updates

**Notify me** when ...

Comment: That will make it quite verbose. Especially since these labels need to be followed up by a trigger situation: 'Notify me when anyone posts', 'E-mail me when I am tagged in a post', etc.